# Creating a view with a single line of string

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am trying to create a view that should contain a single line of string. But I am getting an error. Not sure what is wrong.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW CR_INC_EXPORT_VW AS 
(
  select ',Channel,Expense,Entity,Club,Project' from dual
);
```

View is created with compilation errors.

```
Warning: View created with compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column needs to have a name.  I would also recommend removing the parentheses:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW CR_INC_EXPORT_VW AS
    select ',Channel,Expense,Entity,Club,Project' as col
    from dual;
```